# rsync pull or push over specific port?

Tags: windows, ssh, rsync

I'm looking for assistance with using rsync from a ubuntu server and my local windows machine.  I am running Cygwin64 on my local machine.  I would like to execute rsync on the ubuntu server to move files to my local machine, but I am having trouble with how to specify the directory and specifying a port.  I have forwarded my port 52000 for both TCP and UDP traffic through my router to my computer running Cygwin64 and made an exception for windows firewall settings on this machine.

Here are the parts of my code I am using and need help with

```
rsync --update -- ignore-existing --progress -vure ssh
```

I have seen may ways to specify the port I want to use.  I want to use the options within the command line instead of changing my ssh config file (not sure if I would need to change it on the ubuntu server or my windows machine running Cygwin64).  I have seen -p port, 'ssh -port' and others.  I also am not sure how to write it if I am running the rsync command from the ubuntu server or my windows machine.  I suspect that it is only needed if I am running rsync command from the ubuntu server so that rsync will use port 52000 to connect to my local windows machine.  I suspect that if I tried to run rsync on my windows Cygwin64 machine and specify a port, it would be like my Cygwin64 machine telling the ubuntu server which port to open to ssh incoming traffic and I suspect that the owner of the server has only opened the typical ssh port to traffic (22 right?) so it would just say 'no' and not work (I have tried this and it gives me an error-but maybe I wrote the command line wrong?)

This is the second part I need help with

```
[USER@]HOST:SRC DEST
```

Currently I can successfully use this format and the above rsync commandline options from within cygwin64 to to pull files from the ubuntu server to my local cygwin64 drive.

```
/[user@host]:/home/[user]/downloads/1/ /cygdrive/e/1
```

If I try to change the ssh port how would this need to change?
If I were to run rsync from the ubuntu server how would I change it as I don't know what my windows64 machine running Cygwin64 user name or host (I currently get IPS from my cable company in the USA).

Since there are a number of issues with this, please feel free to help with all or just one.

Thanks.
-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 8022' -av --delete /path/to/source user@remote:/path/to/target
```

I've used port 8022 in my example, and added the `-av --delete` options to rsync, which is a common setup, if you want to sync two folders several times. (Or set your options, as posted in your question.)

If you can connect to SSH server of the machine with the IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx without entering a port number, you can use the following:

```
rsync -e ssh -av --delete /path/to/source user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/path/to/target
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I try this from my local machine it give me an error "rsync: connection to host [host] port 52000: Connection refused".  If I am to run the rsync from the ubuntu server I am not sure how to write the user@remote part.  how do I note my windows cygwin64 machine given my ISP is a cable company in the USA (say I have a static IP address of 12.345.678.90 and I have forwared my router port 52000 to my cygwin64 machine)?

Comment: Can you connect to the target machine via SSH? If so, on which port does SSH run?

Comment: I can connect to the Ubuntu server with out specifying a port with over ssh

Comment: I don't know the IP address of the ubuntu server that I am connecting to only the host name.  I also do not know the user name that I would use if I were to run this line on the ubuntu server.  Would it be my local computer name?  My Windows login name? My ISP user name?

Comment: Then use the host name instead of the IP address. I only mentioned the IP address because you asked for it. Btw, you can find out the IP address of a host with `ping -c1 hostname` or `dig -t A hostname`.

Comment: Ok I got the ubuntu host server IP address and I can connect and run rsync using this instead of the host name.  so this works `rsync --update --ignore-existing --progress -vure ssh user@XX.XXX.XXX.XX:/home/user/downloads/1/ /cygdrive/e/1`

Comment: Ok, so your problem is solved? If not, please let me know what's missing. Otherwise, it would be nice to “accept” the answer. ;)

Comment: ssh into the ubuntu server and issuing the following `rsync --update --ignore-existing --progress -vure ssh /home/user/downloads/1/ /user@XXX.XXXX.XXX.XXX/cygdrive/e/1` does not work.  I get a rsync: mkdir "user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cygdrive/e/1" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: You do not need to log in to the remote machine. Moreover, it is usually impossible, because your remote machine cannot connect to your private IP address. Once more: do not log in via SSH manually. Simply tell rsync your source and destination.

Comment: Thanks.  So my problem of specifying a port to use when using ssh is not solved.  This `rsync --update --ignore-existing --progress -vure 'ssh -p52000' user@XX.XXX.XXX.XX:/home/user/downloads/1/ /cygdrive/e/1` does not work and I get a connection refused.

Comment: Ok, then. Can you connect via SSH *from* your Ubuntu box *to* your Cygwin on Port 52000? NB: You're opening a *second* SSH connection here, from remote to local. If this doesnt work, then maybe your router doesn't forward the SSH connection to your machine.

Comment: so to do this I type `ssh user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:52000` it says name or service not known.  If I drop the :52000 it tried to use port 22 but timed out.  If I use `ssh -p 52000 user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` it times out.  If I change ssh for ping it says unknown host.

Comment: Then maybe you should first set up your router to forward incoming SSH to your machine, and to the correct port. If you're trying to connect to port 52000, but your local SSHD runs on 22, then you must set upd NAPT.

Comment: Yes.  It seems that this is the issue.  I am not sure why my router isn't being forwarded to my local computer.  I'll mark this as answered even though I have a problem.  It seems to be a problem with the port forwarding not my use of rsync.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you get the NA(P)T stuff solved, too, and get the rsync running.